# Computational Hardness of the $k$-Partition Problem with identical numbers/objects?

Tags: algorithms, np-hard, polynomial-time, partitions

The $k$-Partition Problem is NP hard. I want to know if some slight modification of this problem makes it polynomially solvable.

Now consider the set $S=\{a_1,\ldots,a_n\}$ of **IDENTICAL** numbers/objects ($a_1=\ldots=a_n=1$) which needs to be split into $k$ subsets $S_1$, $S_2$, $\ldots$, $S_k$ such that the sums of the subsets are as similar as possible.

Is this problem still  $NP$-hard? Or is there some better solution.

---

My first attempt to solve this was to just evenly split the objects among $k$ subsets. Thus "giving" each subset $\frac{n}{k}$ objects. The only thing that now needs to be considered is rounding fractional solutions in $\frac{n}{k}$.

The most straight forward attempt is to just try all possible roundings of the $k$ subsets, which would yield $2^k$ possible combinations. But this attempt would not be a poly-time algorithm anymore.

While this is far from a hardness proof I somehow have the gut feeling that there must be a polynomial time algorithm for this kind of "simple" problem.

Comment: What exactly are the inputs?  Do we always have $a_1=\dots=a_n=1$, so the only input is $k$?  Or do we always have $a_1=\dots=a_n$, so the only inputs are $a_1,k$?  How do you define how similar a partition is?  You need to give a precise metric for how you'll measure similarity before the problem is well-defined; as it stands, the question is not answerable.  Please state the problem more precisely.  It might be helpful to avoid "just like problem X except make we make change Y" and instead state the problem in a self-contained way.